# Showing a fragment in response to user input causes IllegalStateException

Tags: android, exception, android-fragments

There are plenty of questions regarding the "IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState", however I couldn't find anything dealing with a situation when this exception is raised when showing a fragment **in response to user input**. (The app is for Android 4.0+ only).

In the very illuminating [article by Alex Lockwood](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html) we read:

> A large majority of applications will only ever commit transactions the very first time onCreate() is called and/or in response to user input, and **will never face any problems as a result**.

However it's just what (I think) I'm facing. According to the stack trace, the exception is raised (very occasionally) after a user clicks an Action Bar menu item:

```
Thread: main, Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1265)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1276)
at android.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:541)
at android.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:525)
at android.app.DialogFragment.show(DialogFragment.java:230)
at com.XXX.XXX.XXX.onOptionsItemSelected(SourceFile:XXX)
at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2507)
at android.support.v4.app.g.onMenuItemSelected(SourceFile:372)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:979)
...
```

And this is the method which raises the exception:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.miAbout) {
        final DialogFragment df = DialogAbout.newInstance();
        //Here we have exception very occasionally:
        df.show(getFragmentManager(), "about");
        return true;
    } else {
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

I know I could probably avoid the exception by committing the transaction allowing state loss:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.miAbout) {
        final DialogFragment df = DialogAbout.newInstance();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.add(df, null);
        ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
        return true;
    } else {
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

However, I still don't understand how is it possible that the exception is raised in response to the user click. Since onSaveInstanceState is called after onPause (in post-Honeycomb), it would imply that the activity still handles user clicks after it's paused (what a surprise!). Or perhaps that user clicks are handled with some delay. It would be good to understand what's going on here.

Comment: Is the `onOptionsItemSelected` method implemented in the `Fragment` or the owning `Activity`?  Is there anything else going on in the UI?  Has a different `Fragment` been pushed on to the back stack or otherwise replaced the one you are concerned with?

Comment: The `onOptionsItemSelected` is in the main activity. I don't think any other fragment is pushed on to the back stack at the time. I do use other fragments in the app, but they hide the action bar in their `onCreateView` so the option is not visible/clickable. `DialogFragments` seem to make options in the menu not clickable as well.. unless it depends on Android version/device..

Comment: I can confirm that I am seeing this exact same issue in one of my crash reports. I'm noticing it's a galaxy S2 rooted phone.

Comment: Any luck finding a solution?